# Removing cell phone interference

Tags: mobile, phone, interference

Hi all!

Was doing some location recording in a shopping mall today and recorded a cool sounding rickety lift going down with me in it. Unfortunately I seem to have picked up the sound of my mobile phone interference too! Really annoying. Anyone had any luck removing that kind of blipty-blipt sound before?

If anyone would like to try then heres the sound ;)
http://soundcloud.com/andrewjohnlewis/annoying-mobile

Any help would be appreciated. I reckon I'll probably just have to record it again at some point though :(

Cheers, Andy

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm no expert, but I believe that it is impossible to take out...though I may be wrong.

Comment: EQ alone can't do it, anyway... it looks like cell-phone noise has a much broader EQ range than I'd originally thought.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try simple editing first, using fill from the surrounding regions to cover over the interference you're cutting out. If that fails, I'd go to Izotope RX's Spectrum Repair.

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick search and found this

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=706791

Apparently it works using a vinyl click reduction software coupled with some honeycomb filtering. I can see how this will work in theory, but it's gonna be a lot more pain than re-recording I reckon. :D

Answer (score 0):

The first part of it sounds clean.

Otherwise, I have no clue how to remove that other than maybe 10 hours of spectral analyzing and deleting with Izotope RX.